# Entity Framework 6 Navigation property alias?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have these two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...

    // Foo has N bars, 1 of which is primary
    [ForeignKey("Bar")]
    public int? PrimaryBarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar PrimaryBar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...

    // Foo -> Bar == 1:N
    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

EF now expects me to create a property `BarId` and `Bar` on `Foo` but I don't want that. I want the property to be named **Primary**Bar. I have a 1:N relationship on `Foo`->`Bar` which is reflected elsewhere and not of interest for this question.

EF keeps telling me:

`The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'PrimaryBarId' on type 'X.y.Foo' is not valid. The navigation property 'Bar' was not found on the dependent type 'X.y.Foo'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.`

How do I convince EF to use the `PrimaryBar` (and `PrimaryBarId`) properties (preferrably with an attribute, although using the `DbModelBuilder` in the `OnModelCreating` override is an option too?

**EDIT**

Figured it out. I was missing a:

```
public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
```

on my `Foo` class. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940147/215042) for the explanation.

Comment: Can't you use `[ForeignKey("PrimaryBar")]` on Foo.PrimaryBarId ? I think the exception message is inconsistent with the classes you provided, did you edit them before posting?

Comment: Why is property named `PrimaryBar` of type `Number` instead of type `Bar`?

Comment: @Adimeus: Whoopsie, forgot to rename that in my example. Corrected.

Comment: @smiech That results in: `One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
Foo_PrimaryBar_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Foo_PrimaryBar_Target' in relationship 'Foo_PrimaryBar'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.` I just want a 0..1 on `Foo` to `Bar`.

Comment: @Robll post your Bar=> Foo relation too

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm terribly sorry, but none of the answers were correct. That is: they **are** correct (probably) but I posted my example code for the question wrong. First I forgot to rename some types/properties, then I found a mistake in the the errormessage I posted. And finally it turns out I forgot to post the following code I had on my `Bar` class:

```
class Bar {
    //Didn't post this code:
    [ForeignKey("Foo")]
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

This code was for the 1:N `Foo` has to `Bar`. But since the `PrimaryBar` property implies a 1:0..1 relation EF got confused I guess. What I was missing was the following on my `Foo` class to contain the 1:0..N with `Bar`:

```
class Foo {
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I added this collection et voila; everything works fine now.

Oh, I **did** have to change the ForeignKey to `PrimaryBar` instead of `Bar` indeed as most answers suggested.

I'm terribly sorry and mea culpa: all f*ckups were mine and my own only. I usually don't prefer to post "Foo/Bar/Baz" code instead of actual code but in this case it was a bit difficult and the classes would raise (unrelated) questions on their own which I didn't want to discuss :P

I have upvoted all answers as a "thank you"; however since none of them was the actual solution, again because of my being a dumbass and posting incorrect code/information, I have posted my own answer.

Comment: This may be the solution to your problem but not the answer to the problem as written. As such it is also not useful for other SO users. The question and provided error message was about the `ForeignKey` which the other answers correctly answered. Your answer here only refers to the "1:N relationship on Foo->Bar which is reflected elsewhere and not of interest for this question."

Answer (score 4):

As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#Relationships), the `Name` provided to the `ForeignKeyAttribute` should be the property name not the type or table name. So change your code to this:

```
public int? PrimaryBarId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PrimaryBarId")]
public virtual Bar PrimaryBar { get; set; }
```

Or:

```
[ForeignKey("PrimaryBar")]
public int? PrimaryBarId { get; set; }
public virtual Bar PrimaryBar { get; set; }
```

Comment: The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, **OR**, placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name

Comment: @Adimeus yes I know. Edited to provide both.

Answer (score 2):

First things first.

If your FK property is a nullable int like I see in your code, your relationship will be 0..1-N and not 1-N as it is a nullable foreign key.

Second, I am not very familiar with attribute syntax as it's not ideal to describe your model, and it clutters your object with EF related data. The preferred approach is to declare EF mappings in a separate class which inherits `EntityTypeConfiguration<T>` where `T` is your class.

Now given your classes, first of all you must add a property on `Bar` that maps the N reference, like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos {get;set;}
```

Then you can declare an `EntityTypeConfiguration<Bar>` that, among other settings like defining the primary key and property->column name translation if they don't match, will contain:

```
this
  .HasMany(p => p.Foos)
  .WithOptional(p => p.PrimaryBar)
  .HasForeignKey(p => p.PrimaryBarId);
```

If your FK was an `int` instead of `int?` you would have used `WithRequired` instead of `WithOptional`.

Comment: This isn't actually correct. You don't have to have a navigation property on Foo to have 0..1-N relationship. Have you tried `modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasOptional(f => f.Bar).WithMany().HasForeignKey(f => f.PrimaryBarID);`?

Comment: I know that works too, but having navigation properties on both sides makes the model and the mappings more clear. Your solution is indeed good and working too.

Comment: If you know it works then don't say that you "must" have a navigation property because that is not true.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ForeignKeyAttribute);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true%20ForeignKey) Name parameter is not the entity name but the navigation property name (in your case, as it's a bit more complicated than that).

You should change your code from:

```
[ForeignKey("Bar")]
```

to:

```
[ForeignKey("PrimaryBar")]
```

Comment: Same goes here: The annotation may be placed on the foreign key property and specify the associated navigation property name, **OR**, placed on a navigation property and specify the associated foreign key name